# How to populate data dynamically using var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>

Tags: c#

Could anyone show me how to populate the Galaxy class with data dynamically?

```
public class Galaxy
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Distance {get:set;}
}
```

Instead of populating it manually:

```
var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>
{
    new Galaxy() {Name="Tadpole", Distance="200"},
    new Galaxy() {Name="Andromeda", Distance="300"}
};
```

I want to populate it dynamically. However, this code can't be compiled because of the for loop:

```
var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>
{
    for (int i=0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
    {
       new Galaxy() {Name=someArray[0], distance=someArray[1]}
    } 
};


foreach (Galaxy theGalaxy in theGalaxies)
{
        Console.WriteLine(theGalaxy.Name + "  " + theGalaxy.Distance);
}
```

Comment: is this in java script?

Comment: What language is this? More info please!

Comment: The structure of `someArray` is not really clear. is it an array or arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** use loop in [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), instead try it like:

```
var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>();
for (int i=0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
      theGalaxies.Add(new Galaxy() {Name=someArray[0], distance=someArray[1]});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for showing me some of the various ways of doing it. . It's C#.

Answer (score 3):

```
var theGalaxies = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
                            .Select(x => new Galaxy { Name = "Galaxy" + x.ToString(), Distance = x.ToString() })
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `someArray` alternates galaxy names and distances:

```
var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>();
for (int i=0; i < someArray.Length; i+=2)
    theGalaxies.Add(new Galaxy() {Name=someArray[i], Distance=someArray[i+1]});
```

Parametered constructors are also nice:

```
public class Galaxy
{
    public Galaxy(string name, string distance)
    {
        Name = name;
        Distance = distance;
    }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Distance {get:set;}
}

//...

var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>();
for (int i=0; i < someArray.Length; i+=2)
    theGalaxies.Add(new Galaxy(someArray[i], someArray[i+1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for` loop code to this:

```
var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>();

for (int i=0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
{
    var temp = new Galaxy();
    temp.Name = someArray[0];
    temp.Distance = someArray[1];

    theGalaxies.Add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like c#.

```
var theGalaxies = new List<Galaxy>():
Galaxy galxy;
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
{
    galxy =new Galaxy() {Name = someArray[0], distance = someArray[1]};
    theGalaxies.Add(galxy);
};
```